# Can I send value with request to Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have to send value with request to check it from Firestore rules , like (Recaptcha to avoid spam) or origin (protect my own firebase api) ! is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to pass custom parameters into the Firestore rules. The most common workaround is to pass information as part of the path, although it's definitely kludgy at times.

The best approach for preventing spam is to require your users to log in, and then limit what they can do based on knowing who they are, and knowing what they've done in the past. For example, most apps limit the places users can write to based on their identity, and many apps have a sort-of leveling system where users gradually get more permission as they've been using (and not abusing) the app longer.

Comment: thanks for your reply , what about prevent any Http request from outside my app ! is there any approach for that !

Comment: Nope. Since these are cloud hosted services, they can in principe be reached by anyone with the configuration data. If you suspect that you're seeing significant abuse that you can't prevent with security rules, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: so the best solution for these issues that I should use nodejs (as a server-side) to handle with firebase and protect my Http request , what's your opinion

Comment: My experience is that I can secure databases more than adequately with Firebase security rules, and some role-based/level-based authorization scheme on top/inside of that. If you want you can implement custom auth to give you better control over when a user gets blocked, but you can also implement that on top of an existing auth provider and use the Admin SDK to disable abusive accounts.

Comment: last one question , is there any chance to anyone see my firebase configuration data and take them and try to Signup or make any action from out-side my app like postman !

Comment: Yes, that is completely possible: any data that is in your app can be found by anyone you send that app to. Hence the need for server-side security rules.

Comment: sorry Frank , you mean by server-side security rules to "Firebase security rules " right ?

Comment: That is indeed correct. Firebase's security rules are enforced on the server, which makes it impossible for the client to bypass them. I just realized that I'd missed one option, which is to [add custom claims to the user's ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). But this operation can only be performed in a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions), so likely doesn't apply to your use-case.

Comment: here it's I checked a important point for me and this is example 
" signupByEmail  " I got the API from networks tab like "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=xxxxxxxxx-6sc83QO7uDNJ9h6Vi3GcE&email=admin2@demo.com&password=112233&returnSecureToken=true" with my key and opened the postman and push many request and all return successfully :( how can I protract this process I cant write a Rules on authentication

Comment: I'll assume you got the ID token from the request, which is a bearer token and can be used from other devices. But for someone else but you to be able to get that token, they'd have to be able to intercept your requests. Since all traffic is sent over HTTPS, it is end-to-end encrypted. So interception by someone in the middle is only possible if they can intercept and decrypt your traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your own server-side validation e.g. Recaptcha then you can do the validation in a callable function. If the post data is valid then you can use `firebase-admin` to access your firestore, and if applicable, return any data at the end of the function.