# How can Nodejs send real-time data from Firebase to Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I handle firestore by nodejs and return data to angular - (when I handle data with angular it's will be real-time but with node it's not)
so I want angular listen to any changes on Cloud Firestore.

```
/**
 * this is a route to call function get user By email
 */
router.get('/by/email/:email', (req,res)=>{
    //define email user
    let email = req.params.email;
    //check email param
    if(!email){ return res.status(400).json({message:'EMAILISMISSING'}) }
    //call function get user by email 
    userRef.getByEmail(email, (error,user)=>{
        if(error){ return res.status(400).json(error); }
        else{
            return res.status(200).json(user)
        }
    })
})


/**
 * this is the function bring user by email
 * @requires email
 * @returns @callback
 */
exports.getByEmail = (email,callback)=>{
    userRef.where('email','==',email)
           .get()
           .then(user=>{
                user = fb.renderMultiDocs(user);
                if(!user.length) { return callback(false,null)}
                return callback(false,user[0]);
           })
           .catch(error=>{
               return callback(error,false)
           })
}

/**
* this angular function to call by/email route and return
*/
getUserByEmail(email):any{
  return this._http.get(environment.api+'by/email/'+email)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you connect directly to Firestore from Angular? Firebase works better on the client, not the server side. If you decide to use on the server you will end up with a lot of boilerplate code that Firebase was created to avoid.

Comment: But to answer, you will have to use websockets.

Comment: @RicardoSmania I Know and I need to handle it with angular but I faced issue here it's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648880/can-i-send-value-with-request-to-firestore-rules/54653648#54653648 , and i don't found solution except handle firebase with backend

Comment: You can do some of that with security rules and claims, not the origin whitelist though AFAIK. Have you read the docs on security? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen, from your Angular app, for realtime changes/updates in the Cloud Firestore database, you need to set a listener for either one document or for a set of documents (i.e. an entire collection or a query).

The standard Firestore documentation on this point is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen. This will work independently from how is executed the modification (by a user or by a back-end process, like a node.js app or a Cloud Function).

With Angular, you would probably use the [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) Library, and in particular the techniques described in the following docs:

- For a document: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#using-angularfirestoredocument
- For collections (and queries): https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#streaming-collection-data