# Firestore Security Rules: Passing a request parameter in a get() call?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would want to be able to differentiate a `get()` call in my app from the others.

In Security Rules, I've written in the `read` rule:

`request.resource.data.sign_look == true`

So I would want to be able to write a `get` call sending the true boolean `sign_look` in order to allow it.

Is it possible? I know it's easy to do with rules like `write` since indeed there are data in the request, but such data don't seem to be present in `get` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to pass an arbitrary parameter to security rules.

The two options you have:

1. Pass the value as part of the path that you're reading/writing.
2. Store the value in a custom claim for the user, and then use *that* in your security rules.

Also see:

- [Can I send value with request to Firestore rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648880/can-i-send-value-with-request-to-firestore-rules/54653648#54653648)